# Can I capture clear text request SOAP envelope on a java axis2 client for https?

Tags: java, soap, https, apache-axis

I have a federal government (i.e. extremely security conscience) SOAP service that I have to connect to for a project. The problem I have having is that I am getting the dreaded

```
  SEVERE: SOAP header missing
  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: SOAP header missing
  at  org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:180)
```

Throwable stack trace

I'm generating the client stub with wsdl2code and just calling the

```
 GetResponseTypeDef resp = stub.getRequest(requestypdef, headerTypeDef);
```

headerTypeDef appears to be correctly populated with the header information the service requests.

I want to capture the raw, clear text SOAP xml request being sent out but the endpoint uses https and I have zero visibility into the service. So wireshark really isn't an option.

I'm using the following on linux:
     axis2 1.5.4
     rampart 1.5.1
     wss4j 1.5.10

I am pretty certain that I am sending out the SOAP header, but I need to prove it. This service uses just about every subproject of the WS-* including security, policy, encryption and digital signing so there only about 100 places that can cause this thing to fail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a proxy service like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and have it redirect to your HTTPS endpoint. That way you can trap the call before it gets encrypted and print out the XML payload. On a side note, you may want to work on your accept rate.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to add the `org.apache.axis.transport` logger to see what xml is being sent across the wire?  For example, her is how I have it defined in my log4j config:

```
<category name="org.apache.axis.transport">
    <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
</category>
```